# Why can't I specify the widget as the key (using keyof) to constrain the type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What I expect is:

The `C` component should be mistake, because I set the widget equals "Input", which only has constrained key that is "a" of `type F`, when I set the "b" property's value, it should be mistake, but it isn't.

```
type F = {
  Input: {a: string},
  Select: {b: string},
}

export function createView<
  ComponentName extends keyof F,
>() {
  function InternalView (
    props:  {
      widget: ComponentName
    } & F[ComponentName]
  ) {
    return <div>1</div>
  }
  return InternalView
}

const View = createView()
const C = () => <View widget="Input" a="1" b="1"/>  // should be mistake, property b is not allowed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is how TS Generics work. You need to pass an argument so that the props type will evaluate to your expected type. Consider the following updates to your code:

```
type F = {
  Input: {a: string},
  Select: {b: string},
}

export function createView<
  ComponentName extends keyof F,
>() {
  function InternalView (props: F[ComponentName]) {
    return <div>1</div>
  }
  return InternalView
}

const InputView = createView<"Input">();
const C = () => <InputView a="1" b="2" />; // will cause TS error because of prop b
```

Comment: thanks i resolved by doing this:
```
type F = {
  Input: {a: string},
  Select: {b: string},
}

export function createView() {
  function InternalView <
  ComponentName extends keyof F,
>(
    props:  {
      widget: ComponentName
    } & F[ComponentName]
  ) {
    return <div>1</div>
  }
  return InternalView
}

const View = createView()
const C = () => <View widget="Input" a="1" b="1"/> 
```